# Scrapy finishes process before all urls are processed

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** IMDb site. So, I need to start from page of actors, open it and then for the first 15 films of their filmography open the page of a film and get some information from it. My code is:

```
class Actor(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    bio = scrapy.Field()
    born = scrapy.Field()
    movies = scrapy.Field()

class Film(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    cast = scrapy.Field()


class ImdbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imdb"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?gender=male%2Cfemale&ref_=nv_cel_m',]

    def parse_cast(self, response):
      actor = response.meta['actor']
      filmsToProcess = response.meta['filmsToProcess']

      film = Film()
      ... getting some information about filf
      actor['movies'].append(film)

      if not filmsToProcess:
        yield actor
        return
      else:
         film = filmsToProcess.pop()
         url = 'https://www.imdb.com' + film.extract().strip() 
         yield scrapy.Request(url + 'fullcredits', callback=self.parse_cast, meta = {
          "actor": actor,
          'url': url,
          "filmsToProcess": filmsToProcess
      })  


    def parse_bio(self, response):
      actor = Actor()
      #... getting some information about the actor
      actor["movies"] = list()

      # getting list of films from filmography
      filmsToProcess = response.xpath('//*[@id="filmography"]/div[@class="filmo-category-section"]')[0].xpath('./div[contains(@class, "filmo-row")]/b/a/@href')[:10]
      film = filmsToProcess.pop()
      url = 'https://www.imdb.com' + film.extract().strip() 

      yield scrapy.Request(url + 'fullcredits', callback=self.parse_cast, meta = {
          "actor": actor,
          'url': url,
          "filmsToProcess": filmsToProcess
      })

    def parse(self, response):
      table_rows = response.xpath('.//*[@class="lister-list"]/div')
      for row in table_rows[:25]:
        name = row.xpath("./div[@class='lister-item-content']/h3/a/text()").extract_first().strip()  
        url = 'https://www.imdb.com/' + row.xpath("./div[@class='lister-item-content']/h3/a/@href").extract_first().strip() + '/'  
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_bio, meta = {
               "url": url,
               "name": name
              })
```

The problem is that as result I'm getting only 15 actors (but in parse method I iterate over 25) and some actors do not get into the result for som reason. I think it may be because of multitheading, but why does **scrapy** finish the process before all actors are processed?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. Also, it's __scrapy__ not scrappy.

Comment: Combining the films and actors in this way is making things quite complicated. If you don't mind having the movie information separate from the actor information this would become much simpler. Would that be ok or do you really need the nested information like you have above?

Comment: It is not necessary for films to be nested in actors, but I cant find another way to iterate over all the films on actor's pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the reason you aren't seeing all the actors is because you don't yield the actor information until you've parsed all their films. `scrapy` filters out duplicate requests so if you have any duplicate films I think it will just stop that chain. One (untested) option would be to just pass the [`dont_filter`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) option to your movie `Request`s so it repeats duplicate requests.

If you can separate out the actors and films then things become much more straight forward.

I'd parse the actor information all from the actor page rather than passing anything in `meta`, since all the info is then on a single page. An example to get you started is below.

```py
class IMDBSpider(Spider):
    name = "imdb"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?gender=male%2Cfemale&ref_=nv_cel_m"
    ]   

    def parse(self, response):       
        for actor in response.css(".lister-item-header > a")[:25]:
            yield response.follow(actor, callback=self.parse_actor)

    def parse_actor(self, response):
        actor = response.css("h1 > .itemprop::text").get()
        movie_links = response.css(".filmo-category-section > div > b > a")
        movies = movie_links.css("::text").getall()
        # bio = ...
        # born = ...
        yield {"actor": actor, "url": response.url, "movies": movies}

        for link in movie_links[:15]:
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_movie)
    
    def parse_movie(self, response):
        # parse the movie page from here
```